# What is the difference between the term "actor" and "agent"?

Tags: terminology, theta-role

I've worked quite a lot on agency so far. Today i've read the paper "Two routes to actorhood: lexicalized potencx to act and identification of the actor role" (Franzel et al. 2015) and i'm wondering why they use the term "actor" instead of "agent". Thanks for any help!

Comment: What context does your quotation stem from?

Comment: it's the title of a paper. The authors are neurolinguists and they did a questionaire study and an EEG

Comment: A bit of history: http://systemictheory.blogspot.com/2017/12/actor-vs-agent.html